# javascript catch multiple errors with one catch

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have 3 functions with promises:

```
function1().then(() => {
  function2().then(() => {
    function3().then(() => {      
    })
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Would I be able to catch the error returned by any of the 3 functions? If not, what should I do in order to catch the errors returned by any of the functions' promises with one statement?

Comment: No, you will only catch errors in `function1` because the other two aren't part of the same promise chain. Minimal example: `Promise.resolve().then(() => { Promise.reject("whoops!") }).catch((err) => console.log(err));`

Comment: Is there a way that I can catch the errors with one statement?

Comment: Yes, make them all part of the same promise chain: `Promise.resolve().then(() => Promise.reject("whoops!")).catch((err) => console.log(err));`

Comment: Simplest form: `function1().then(function2).then(function3).then(() => { /* do whatever */ }).catch(console.log);`

Comment: Even better, `Promise.resolve().then(function1).then(function2).then(function3).then(() => { /* do whatever */ }).catch(console.log);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling and chaining them in the bodies, return the resulting promise and chain the `.then` clauses.

```js
function1().then(() => {
  // TODO: Something.
  return function2();
}).then(() => { // <-- This `.then` waits until `function2` has finished executing
  // TODO: Something.
  return function3();
}).then(() => { // <-- This `.then` waits until `function3` has finished executing
  // TODO: Something.
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest change is to just `return` the inner promises.  That will cause their rejections to propagate upwards to the single `.catch()`, like this:

```
function1().then(() => {
  return function2().then(() => {
    return function3().then(() => {      
    })
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

But, this successive nesting of promises is less-than-ideal (some would call it an anti-pattern).  If you really want things sequenced these days and you're using a modern JS environment, then you would sequence things and catch errors in one place with `await`:

```
async someFunction() {
    try {
        let val1 = await function1();
        let val2 = await function2();
        let val3 = await function3();
    } catch(e) {
        // catch any rejections from the above three `await` statements here
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Using `await` also makes it a lot easier to see the code flow and to gather results from multiple asynchronous calls in one scope.

---

Without `await`, you could also flatten your original code:

```
function1().then(() => {
    return function2().then(() => {
    })
}).then(() => {
    return function3().then(() => {      
    })
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
})
```

But, most people will consider the `await` implementation to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can eighter use async/await or `then` without nested:

```
function1().then(() => Promise.resolve(val1))
.then(() => Promise.resolve(val2))
 ...
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

With async/await:

```
try {
    await function1();
    await function2();
    ...
} catch(err) {
    console.log(error);
}
```