# Axios: Chain multiple requests using data of one request in another

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I need to make a bunch of API calls and combine their data finally like this

```
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox'),
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/phantomjs')
])
.then(responseArr => {
  //this will be executed only when all requests are complete
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[0].data.created_at);
  console.log('Date created: ', responseArr[1].data.created_at);
});
```

But I also want to use the data received in one API in the other API call. Kind of like this

```
data = axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox'),
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+data.user);
```

How do I use this for like 5 API calls?

Comment: Sequence calls by either using `await` or nesting `.then()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883528/javascript-catch-multiple-errors-with-one-catch/62886195#62886195).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will use async-await for this.

```
async function fetchData(){
try {
 const response = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/mapbox");
 const res = response.data;
 const getUser = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${res.user}`);
 const getWhatever = getUser.data;
 ......
 ......
 } catch (error) {
 console.log(error)
 }
}
```

You could also use a nested .then method whenever you get the results and then use that to make another request. But I think async-await is better.